# Swift - Dictionary Fetching API

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am creating a simple iOS app where i fetch data from API ( open Source ) using the below function :

```
    private func fetchCurrencies() {
    if let url = URL(string: "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=a5b8f8bd7583e32252946741********"){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else{
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Rates.self, from: data)
                    let array = decodedData.rates
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("error decoding")
                }

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

and the data model is :

```
 struct Rates: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
 }
```

Below is part of my API Data :

```
"success": true,
"timestamp": 1590762665,
"base": "EUR",
"date": "2020-05-29",
"rates": {
    "AED": 4.08666,
    "AFN": 85.22449,
    "ALL": 124.556499,
    "AMD": 538.156223,
    "ANG": 1.996181,
    "AOA": 645.803727,
    "ARS": 76.250753,
    "AUD": 1.672917,
    "AWG": 2.002692,
    "AZN": 1.896163,
    "BAM": 1.95413,
    "BBD": 2.245466,
    "BDT": 94.371782,
    // and so on .....
```

Fetching data is working fine and i receive the rates but i can't figure out how to publish these data inside my table view ( for example : cell text the currency & cell details text as rate ) also i feel my model is not structured as supposed to be, so what is the proper way should be to fetch the rates data & publish them inside my table view as modeling the data, fetching them & table cell data insertion .

Below is part of what appears when i print array into the console :

```
 ▿ 168 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
   - key : "HKD"
   - value : 8.615716
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
   - key : "IMP"
   - value : 0.900216
 ▿ 2 : 2 elements
   - key : "ZWL"
   - value : 357.865214
 ▿ 3 : 2 elements
   - key : "LBP"
   - value : 1676.38247
```

I hope i made myself clear ,

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I would use a `Rate` struct with the `String` and `Double` (or even better for currency use `NSDecimalNumber`) properties. Then make an array of `Rate` that you can use for your table's datasource.

Comment: Firstly , i used the same way you suggested but it kept giving me error decoding data , i would be grateful if you post your code suggestion into the answers so i can get more clear image of your approach :)

Comment: Post your json into app.quicktype.io, it will give you matching data model.

Comment: This is what i got :) 
struct Empty: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
}

Comment: Exactly ! , submit the link in answers in order to be able to tick you answer and give you a +1 if interested , thank you :)

Comment: Just posting links in an answer is not encouraged, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to combine all dictionaries to a single one

```
let flattenedArray = array
.flatMap { $0 }
.reduce([String:String]()) { (var dict, tuple) in
    dict.updateValue(tuple.1, forKey: tuple.0)
    return dict
}
```

next, you can use flattenedArray like I do below

```
            var i: Int = 0
            //use i as a counter
            while i < 168 {

            self.arrayOfRates.append(Array(flattenedArray)[i].value)
            self.arrayOfCurrency.append(Array(flattenedArray)[i].key)
                i = i + 1

            }
```

then set up your tableView using arrayOfRates as cell details, and arrayOfCurrency as cell text.

if you need help setting up tableView watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJUmrdfgbbA

Comment: Thank you , my rates array actually contains array of dictionaries that has rates and currency , and i can't have access to each of them because every dictionary key value is different based into currency iso , how can i split the dictionary array into 2 arrays as you suggested one for rates and one for currencies while it has no static key value ?

Comment: Please check my question modification where what is printed on my console as key & values of the dictionary :)

Comment: Avoid using two array for data that have sense only if they are together. Sorting/Filtering the tableView is adding difficulties.

Comment: I reviewed the issue, please check my edited answer